# ncat ssl generates input/output error

Tags: kali-linux

I'm currently attempting to use ncat to bind a cmd shell in Windows for remote access in Kali Linux.

On Windows, I first run:

```
ncat --exec cmd.exe -vnl Port --ssl
```

On Kali Linux, I then run:

```
ncat -v WindowsIP Port --ssl
```

I then receive a cmd prompt on Kali Linux, however, upon attempting to run any commands, I am met with no response. After pressing Enter multiple times, I receive an error:

```
Ncat: Input/Output error.
```

With no further details. I am running Ncat 7.31 on Kali Linux and Windows.

I have attempted using a different port, generating my own certificates and keys in a .pem format using openSSL and specifying these certificates and keys using `--ssl-key` and `--ssl-cert` to no avail.

Comment: Try using `openssl s_client -connect WindowsIP:Port` on the Kali side to see if SSL is in fact up and running properly... If that doesn't work, use `nmap` to verify that you've got connectivity at the TCP level between client and server.  It may be something as simple as Windows Firewall being up...

Comment: That command shows that a certificate exists and prompts me for input into CMD. However, the same error is generated. I have Windows Firewall allowing the port for ncat already and I have also disabled Kali Linux's firewall using `ufw disable`.

Comment: I think this can be solved by installing the latest Ncat version on Windows

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `--sctp` option with both of your commands.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Some Google'ing did lead me to attempt to use this flag, however, upon entering into the Windows computer, I immediately receive an error: `Ncat: Unable to open any listening sockets. QUITTING`. My firewall is disabled and I am running the cmd as Administrator.

Comment: Try `ncat --exec cmd.exe -vvv -n -l -p [port] --ssl`

Comment: I appear to get the same error, but I assume -vvv is the debug mode from the logs I'm getting. The last message while I receive the cmd prompt on Kali Linux and before it throws errors says `NCAT DEBUG: Register subprocess 000000E0 at index 0.` 

The next message I receive after attempting to remotely run a command is `Unregister subprocess 000000E0 from index 0.` Followed by a `Subprocess still running, terminating it`, `exit code 259`, `terminating subprocesses`, `max_index 1`. The full log is here: pastebin.com/1ymfV5xV

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with TLS 1.2. ncat 7.6 no longer uses it since Sep 18. Jul 17's ncat 7.5 does.

Download the version you need from the nmap distros:
https://nmap.org/dist/?C=M&O=D

Comment: This is difficult to read, and it is not clear from your answer that the TLS version is the problem. Can you confirm?